# How to reference ranges/columns of a table in an inactive sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to reference a data range table on an inactive sheet on Excel with VBA.

I can reference the sheet by making it active:

```
Sheets("DTC").Select

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DTC_Table").ListColumns("Delay").DataBodyRange.Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(--IsColour(0,K2),""Active"",(IF(--IsColour(2500134,K2),""Active"",IF(--IsColour(4210752,K2),""Active"",IF(V2=""No"","""",""Inactive"")))))"
```

but I don't know why referencing an inactive sheet does not seem to work:

```
Sheets("DTC").ListObjects("DTC_Table").ListColumns("Delay").DataBodyRange.Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(--IsColour(0,K2),""Active"",(IF(--IsColour(2500134,K2),""Active"",IF(--IsColour(4210752,K2),""Active"",IF(V2=""No"","""",""Inactive"")))))
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: You can't `Select` something that isn't on the `ActiveSheet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do a `Select`. You already have the reference. Try:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(<your sheet name here>)
    .ListObjects("DTC_Table").ListColumns("Delay").DataBodyRange.Formula = <your formula here>
End With
```

Might be worth reading why we shouldn't use things like `Select` and `Activate`

Comment: Thank you. I found the below, which I will read. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba